# Question on momentum space Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

In the lecture, my professor wrote:

With potential $V(x)=-Fx$, where $F$ is a constant, in momentum space the Schrodinger equation takes the form
$$
\left[\frac{p^2}{2m}-i\hbar F\frac{d}{dp}\right]\varphi_E(p)=E\varphi_E(p)
$$

I know I have to transform the potential using Fourier transform, but I don't get $V(p)=-i\hbar F\frac{d}{dp}$. Can someone explain how he gets $V(p)$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a straightforward substitution. In momentum space the [position operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator) is:

$$ \hat{x} = i \hbar \frac{d}{dp} $$